# Cleaning eclipse project without cleaning depending projects

Tags: java, eclipse

I have WEBPAP project depending on many others projects,

The clean of the WEBPAP project, cause the build of all others, could i prevent this? without closing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in Eclipse, when you selected **Project -> Clean...** from the menu, it allows you to select the projects which you'd like to clean.

---

#### Edit 1

- Disable Eclipse's refresh on startup: **Preferences -> General -> Startup and Shutdown -> Refresh workspace on startup**
- Disable automatic build: **Menu -> Project -> Build Automatically**

If you're using project management tools such as Maven, you may want to take a look at its specific build settings.

Comment: @NassimMOUALEK Define "not helping". What would be your expected behaviour of Eclipse?

Comment: but its looks, that this is hapening only when i restart eclipse, it rebuild all projects from scratch

Comment: it just that it takes so long to rebuild all project and it become very annoying

Comment: Thanks, i check the "Refresh workspace on startup" its already unchecked, and i am already aware about "Build Automatically", but i will validate your response just for the effort, thanks again

Comment: @NassimMOUALEK But wait, you're saying it didn't work? Well that's not quite good. Are you using Maven by any chance?

Comment: yes all projets are maven, but i dont know what should i check